# Codeigniter 2.2: File Upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having problem dealing with File Uploads in CodeIgniter 2.2.
I am able to create its specific folder destination, but I am unable to upload the file that I have selected.

Here's my **Controller**:

```
function create_report()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {

            $this->create_model->set_report();


            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Success! You created a Report!');
            #$redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');


     }
   else
   {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Oops! You have to Login');
     //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }      

}
```

and here is my **Model**:

```
function set_report()
    {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {       
                $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

                if($_FILES['userfile']['name'] != NULL)
                {       
                        $main_dir = './FILES/'.$this->input->post('patientname').'/';
                        // Check if User Folder is already created. Create New if none exist
                        if(!is_dir($main_dir)){
                        mkdir($main_dir, 0777);
                        }

                        $target_dir = './FILES/'.$this->input->post('patientname').'/'.$this->input->post('session_id').'/';
                        // Check if Session Folder is already created. Create New if none exist
                        if(!is_dir($target_dir)) {
                        mkdir($target_dir, 0777);
                        }

                        $config['upload_path'] = './FILES/'.$this->input->post('patientname').'/'.$this->input->post('session_id').'/';
                        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|docx|xlsx|doc|pdf|csv|zip|rar|7zip|ppt|pptx';


                        $this->load->library('upload', $config);



                        $data2 = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());



                }

                $data = array(                      
                    'session_id' => $this->input->post('session_id'),   
                    'report_creator' => $session_data['username'],
                    'report_patientname' => $this->input->post('patientname'),
                    'report_patientid' => $this->input->post('patientid'),
                    'report_subject' => $this->input->post('subject'),                      
                    'report_description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                    'report_time' => $this->input->post('date'),                        
                    'report_date' => $this->input->post('time')                     

                );

                return $this->db->insert('session_reports', $data);

    }


}
```

I've been trying to solve this and I haven't figure out the key.
I hope anyone could help me with this.

Comment: So ? What is your error ? Did you try to display `$this->upload->display_errors()` to see what's wrong ?

Comment: By the way, you forgot `$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)` to upload your file. Read the documentation : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: are you sure `mkdir($main_dir, 0777)` is working ??

Comment: @VincentDecaux well there is no error showing, I also tried doing
` $field_name = "userfile";
$this->upload->do_upload($field_name); `

Comment: @Abdulla. Yes. It is working

Comment: what you do by `$data2 = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());` ?? Upload??

Answer (score 1):

I believe, I have failed to initialize the config.

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

That solved my problem. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
$data2 = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
```

and replace this to that

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else
{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
```

Load Library

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Alternately you can set preferences by calling the `initialize()` method. Useful if you auto-load the class:

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

[Codeigniter file Upload](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=file%20uploading%20class#the-controller)